# Android doesn't save Thumbnails in Cache

Tags: android

I notice a different behavior in android management of thumbnails.
This is my code:

```
String[] sProjection = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};

Cursor oCur = oActivity.getContentResolver().query(
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    sProjection,"",null,MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

do{

...

Bitmap oBmp = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(oActivity.getContentResolver(),bmpID,
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,null);

...

}while (oCur.moveToNext());
```

And then after loading all thumbnails, I make some elaborations with some of them.

With my mobile (Android 4.1.2) after loading all thumbnails for the first time (for example with new photos or after cleaning cache in Media Storage), "do while" loop is very quick because all the tumbanails are already created and saved in cache.

With another one (same Android version) every time you execute the loop there are no improvements of velocity, because it doesn't save them but it recalculate them all (viewed with the messages in Eclipse LogCat).

Why do this happen?! Is there a way to solve this issue and to force Android save thumbnails in cache memory?

Thanks a lot for the help, any suggestion is greatly appreciated.